# What is the best way to rebuild a object from different views?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying implement add/edit control for my DTO object.
I have created a AddContainerView.
The AddContainerView is constructed with a view for each field in the DTO as its purpose is to show the status and progress of the add/edit(See pic for example).

Orange = Current View

Grey = Yet to Attempt

Green = Valid Entry

Red = Invalid Entry

[image: 1]

Each field view has the interface IAdd as below:

Field being the name of the associated field and Value being the property to bind to for the value

```
public interface IAdd
{
    bool IsSelected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    bool IsValid
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    bool Attempted
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    string Field
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    object Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The problem:

Because each of these views has its own property(Value) I need to recreate the DTO or be setting the referenced DTO from the AddContainerView.

The Question:
What is the best way of achieving this without static variables or pointers?

Update:
AddContainerView.xaml
http://pastebin.com/Jf7XjyjR

AddContainerViewModel:
http://pastebin.com/pM2Ye0qx

IAdd:
http://pastebin.com/GZCU0j3z

Update 2(Possible Solution):

```
public void Save()
{
    T tempObject = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    Views.ToList().ForEach(v =>
    {
        var cv = (v as IAdd);
        tempObject.GetType().GetField(cv.Field).SetValue(tempObject, cv.Value);
    });
    //Database update...
}
```

Comment: It is still very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Yea I'm finding it hard to explain :( I'm trying to create a list of views that each update one field of the parent views property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a save method in the AddContainerViewModel.

This has a List of the available views each view implements IAdd.

In the constructor of the AddContainerViewModel I pass a Type(ObjectType), this is the type that has each of the fields. As each IAdd has the field name I then create a new object of that Type for saving and loaded each of the properties of that type based off the field name and value in IAdd.

The ID part is a bit of a hack to make it work for Edits as well. I passed a ID of 1 or greater to signify a update and 0 to add new. Because one of my tables in the database has Id instead of ID I unfortunately had to check for both properties.

```
var idProp = tempObject.GetType().GetProperty("ID");
if(idProp == null)
    idProp = tempObject.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
if(idProp != null)
    idProp.SetValue(tempObject, ID);
```

The solution:

```
public void Save()
{
    var tempObject = Activator.CreateInstance(ObjectType);
    var idProp = tempObject.GetType().GetProperty("ID");
    if(idProp == null)
        idProp = tempObject.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
    if(idProp != null)
        idProp.SetValue(tempObject, ID);
    Views.ToList().ForEach(v =>
    {
        var cv = (v as IAdd);
        var f = tempObject.GetType().GetProperty(cv.Field);
        f.SetValue(tempObject, cv.Value);
    });
    //Database update
    SaveHelpers.SaveObject(tempObject);
    Navigator.Nav.Back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it like this:

- `AddContainerView` has a `ContentControl` element for the currently selected field view and the overview control (with all the circles)
- `AddContainerView` is connnected to a view model that has a `IAdd` property called `SelectedField` (the currently selected field view binds to that) and a collection property (maybe `IEnumerable<IAdd>`) called `AllFields` for all the available fields (the overview-circle control binds to it)
- Have template views for the `IAdd` objects that `AddContainerView` knows of (for 'SelectedField' binding) - textboxes, checkboxes, with labels, you name it...
- Because you bind `SelectedField` to your field control, you always have the latest values stored
- Whenever somebody goes forward or back (or maybe even clicks on a circle) you reset the `SelectedField` property with the newly chosen one

Comment: I've add my current implementation of AddContainerView.xaml to the question. As you can see I've got a content control for the current view and a ItemsControl for the Status circles. The 4th and 5th bullets I don't quite understand.

Comment: Can I change the binding dynamically? eg. CurrentValue = {Binding PropertyName + "." + CurrentView.FieldName}

Comment: I assume that your `IAdd` implementation is both view and (view) model. Since you set the new `IAdd` instance to `CurrentView` everything should be working fine. Can you post it as well?

Comment: Added IAdd.cs to post

Comment: Added possible solution will test soon.